# How can i save Content-Disposition form-data to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsdata

I've made a NSString out of a NSData object:

```
   NSData* data = request.HTTPBody;
    NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now I have the NSString which gave me the following NSLog:

```
    WebKitFormBoundaryA7rpc3udSxxsvBFm

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="username"

Testusernamevalue

------WebKitFormBoundaryA7rpc3udSxxsvBFm

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

Testpasswordvalue

------WebKitFormBoundaryA7rpc3udSxxsvBFm--
```

How can i save this two values of "username" and "password" into a single NSString for username and passwort?

Thanks for your help.
Best regards
Eddi

Comment: To be sure I understand, you have a long string that includes newlines, and you'd like to find in it two strings delimited by name=" * " ?  How will you know which is name and which is password?

Comment: No I have problems with special characters in a php-form. So i changed the form to enctype="multipart/form-data". Then i got the values of the form after name="username" and after name="password". I just need two NSStrings with the Values "Testusernamevalue" and "Testpasswordvalue" (e.g. in the first post)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question to mean that we want the string values on the lines that follow the "Content-Disposition" lines.  For that, we'll need to walk through the lines, keeping state about finding the delimiting lines and their type (username or password)

```
NSArray *components = [theLongContentDispositionString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableDictionary *values = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSString *key = nil;
for (NSString *line in components) {
    if (key && line.length) {
        values[key] = line;
        key = nil;
    } else if ([line hasPrefix:@"Content-Disposition"]) {
        // does the line contain "username"?  Assume password if not
        NSRange r = [line rangeOfString:@"username"];
        key = (r.location == NSNotFound)? @"password" : @"username";
    }
}
```

The values dictionary should end up looking like:

```
{
    password = "non-empty line after Content-Disposition line with password";
    username = "non-empty line after Content-Disposition line with username";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me further.

Comment: @Eddi - sure.  That is typically expressed by marking the answer correct.